# Impossible to show CakePhp CheckBox

Tags: checkbox, cakephp-2.0

I'm developping my application and I got stuck with a little problem.
I have to use checkboxes but when declaring them i got nothing on my view, i mean that the checkbox doesn't appear

```
echo $this->Form->input('Class.id', array( 
    'options'=>$classes,
    'type'=>'select',
    'multiple' => 'checkbox'));
```

Please could anyone help! 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `echo $this->Form->checkbox('name');`

Comment: A short paragraph or even a sentence or two by way of explanation would have gone a long way into making this a great answer.